# How to check the file size on Application Server in Runtime?

Tags: abap, application-server, dms, netweaver

Dear SAP & DMS experts,

I would like to know how to check the size of the file being uploaded on the Application Server -AL11- **at runtime**.

My problem ist the following:

When using the FM `HTTP_GET_FILE` to upload the DMS files (original draws of Materials) on the Application Server (T-code AL11), I **sometimes** face the following problem:

The uploaded files in the app server are picked up incomplete by another report (SAP background job).
This may be due to overlapping of both reports (the 1st report uploading the documents into the app server and the 2nd report (job) reading it and sending it as Email).

Up to this point, my attempt to solve the problem was:
During the 2nd report, the size of the original file is compared to the uploaded file. If both sizes are unequal, wait 1 second and compare again until both sizes are equal.
Unfortunately I couldn’t implement this solution because I don’t have access to the file size during uploading.

If it is not possible to determine the file size, are there any other ideas to avoid this problem?

I hope that I could give a clear idea of the problem.

I am thankful for all help and information.

Khaled

Edit (Just to clarify the use of `HTTP_GET_FILE`):

1. Get the link of original file using the FM `CVAPI_DOC_VIEW`
2. Then, "upload" the file using the returned `pfx_url` to the sap application server (AL11)

Comment: That's a well-known problem for systems based on FTP. One possible solution is to change the program which uploads the file to the application server this way: first upload a little file which contains the name and size of the other file, then upload the big file. The background job will probably read the little file first, so it's able to know when the big file is fully uploaded, PS: I don't see how `HTTP_GET_FILE` can by itself only "upload" a file (from HTTP) to the application server.

Comment: @SandraRossi Thank you very much for your Feedback!

The problem is I couldnt find a way for the background job to check the upload status: meaning the dynamic file size that is on the application server (AL11) at the moment the background job tries to read the file from the app server while the upload can still be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the size of a file on the application server, nothing is proposed out-of-the-box by SAP. You have to use:

- either use commands of the operating system (define it in transaction code SM49 and invoke it via function module `SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE`)
- or use the kernel C programs `C_DIR_READ_START`, `C_DIR_READ_NEXT`, `C_DIR_READ_FINISH`.
- another solution for small files is to do it in ABAP.

You may find some examples in the web for the two first possibilities.

Calculate the file size in ABAP (slow performance for big files) :

```
data read_buffer type x length 1000.
data(fullpath) = `/tmp/file`.
data(file_size) = 0.
open dataset fullpath for input in binary mode.
do.
  read dataset fullpath into read_buffer ACTUAL LENGTH data(actual_length).
  if actual_length = 0.
    exit.
  endif.
  add actual_length to file_size.
enddo.
close dataset fullpath.
```